# visibility of LOD DAE object in Three JS

Tags: three.js

i'm trying to use the THREE.LOD object in my ThreeJS scene. i've been inspired by http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lod.html

But I wanted to push the idea further and use DAE model (using this loader : http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html)

Problem is i can't switch the visibility of the lod level. First, i tried an automated one in my Render function (based on distance to camera, found in the  example):

```
 this.m_Scene.traverse( function ( object ) {

    if ( object instanceof THREE.LOD ) {

        object.update( that.m_Camera );
    }
} );
```

As it wasn't working (All my lod were displayed at the same time). I try something more manual. and it appears the Object3D.visibility attribute isn't really used by the renderer, or not inherited by children.

As far as I understand, this attribute is for meshes. But i'm not sure it's checked at render time.

So this doesn't work as expected:

```
var LodTemporaryObject = new THREE.LOD();
function LoadLod1()
{
    //TEST COLLADA LOADER
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

    loader.load(Lod2Path, function ( collada ) {

    dae = collada.scene;

    dae.scale.x = dae.scale.y = dae.scale.z = 0.1;
    dae.updateMatrix();
    dae.visible = false;  //THIS HAS NO EFFECT
    LodTemporaryObject.addLevel(dae,100);

    AddLodToScene(LodTemporaryObject ); //where the lod is added to the threeJS scene object
} );
```

}

**so question** : how do I actually set (in)visible any Object3D or subScene ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx to WestLangley answer above, i came up with an recursive solution to my problem:

first, a recursive function to update visibility of children to match the parent's:

```
function SetChildrenVisible(parent)
{
    if(parent instanceof THREE.Object3D)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i< parent.children.length; i ++)
        {
            parent.children[i].visible = parent.visible;
            SetChildrenVisible(parent.children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

then in my render loop:

```
this.m_Scene.traverse( function ( object ) {

    if ( object instanceof THREE.LOD ) {
        //save all lodLevel state before updating
        var oldVisible =[]; object.visible;
        for(var i = 0; i< object.children.length; i++)
        {
            oldVisible.push(object.children[i].visible)
        }
        //Update Lod 
        object.update( that.m_Camera );

        //Check for changes and update accordingly
        for(var i = 0; i< object.children.length; i++)
        {
            if(oldVisible[i] != object.children[i].visible )
            {
                SetChildrenVisible(object.children[i]);
            }
        }

    }

} );
```

Goal is to only update object whose attribute changed.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: The answer below is outdated. Visibility is now inherited. See, for example, [Show children of invisible parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567369/show-children-of-invisible-parents/25571352#25571352).

three.js r.71

---

Visibility is not inherited by children with `WebGLRenderer`.

The work-around is to use a pattern like so:

```
object.traverse( function( child ) {

    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

        child.visible = false;

    }

}
```

three.js r.64