# How to create invisible mesh?

Tags: three.js

I'd like to have a collection of objects that appear to be floating free in space but are actually connected to each other so that they move and rotate as one.  Can I put them inside a larger mesh that is itself completely invisible, that I can apply transformations to?  I tried setting `transparency: true` on the `MeshNormalMaterial` constructor, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

As a simple representative example: say I want to render just one pair of opposite corner cubies in a Rubik's Cube, but leave the rest of the Cube invisible.  I can rotate the entire cube and watch the effect on the smaller cubes as they move together, or I can rotate them in place and break the illusion that they're part of a larger object.

In this case, I imagine I would create three meshes using `BoxGeometry` or `CubeGeometry`, one with a side length triple that of the other two. I would add the two smaller meshes to the larger one, and add the larger one to the scene.  But when I try that, I get one big cube and can't see the smaller ones inside it.  If I set `visible` to false on the larger mesh, the smaller meshes disappear along with it, even if I explicitly set `visible` to true on them.

Comment: Each `THREE.Object3D` has a `.visible` attribute. The Object gets rendered if the flag is true. Take a look at http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D

Comment: But that seems to make its child objects invisible as well...

Comment: yes but you can override the flag for the children by traversing down the scene-graph.

Comment: doesn't help.  explicitly `visible` children are still invisible if the parent is.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567369/show-children-of-invisible-parents/25571352#25571352

Comment: Whups, looks like this is a dupe.  Thanks, @WestLangley!

Answer (score 0):

Group them inside an `Object3D`.

```
var parent = new THREE.Object3d();
parent.add( child1 ); // etc

parent.rotation.x = 2; // rotates group
```

Comment: How is this different than when `parent` is specifically a Mesh instead of a generic Object3D?

Comment: Everything in the scene inherits from Object3D. A Mesh just has polygons+vertices etc drawn with it.