# Objects do not render if the scene container is hidden from view when the object is being rendered

Tags: three.js

As already asked [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11237)(but I couldn't any solution online for that); I have a container and I render objects successfully but when I hide/show the container's parents The rendered scene is gone. how can I fix this?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25571352/1461008) is helpful.

Comment: @WestLangley nope. not the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps a simple jsfiddle would be helpful to explain your issue.